# Switching the first and last letter of a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have to write a method to switch the first and last letter of a string. For example the string "java" would become "aavj".

Here is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class printTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password;
        password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your password");
        int length = password.length();
        String firstChar = password.substring(0, 1);
        String lastChar = password.substring(length - 1);

        password = lastChar + password + firstChar;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, password);
    }
}
```

With that code I get the following output "ajavaj" when I input "java", so how can I fix this? I need to switch the first two letters and still have the middle of the string. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to substring password on this line:

```
password = lastChar + password.substring(1, length-1) + firstChar;
```

Answer (score 3):

By doing `password =  lastChar +  password + firstChar;` you are concatenating the original password String with the two other Strings i.e. `lastChar` & `firstChar`. By doing this you will actually get a new String with `lastChar` and `firstChar` appended and not swapped.

Also, Strings are immutable and every time you are trying to manipulate it, you are ending up creating a new String. You should use `char` array instead to avoid this problem.

Try this piece of code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class printTest
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          /* Capture Password */
          String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your password");
          char[] pass = password.toCharArray();

          /* Swap Logic */
          char temp = pass[0];
          pass[0] = pass[pass.length - 1];
          pass[pass.length - 1] = temp;

          /* Show MessageDialog */
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new String(pass));
     }
}
```

Comment: Explain why you think this code is correct and why it works.

Comment: @Markoto Added additional information. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: Your explanation on the `char` array doesn't make sense, since you're creating a new string *anyway*.  It could be said that you're creating one less String instance, but that's not a convincing enough argument to use `char` arrays here.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your response. But we are actually creating two less String instances. `password =  lastChar +  password + firstChar;` is also creating a new String apart from `firstChar` and `lessChar` in the original code.

Comment: Performance-wise this is probably better. But JVM could be smart enough to optimize other `substring` solutions as fast as this one. In practice it's probably not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class printTest
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     String password;
    password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your password");
    int length = password.length();
      String password_changed = password.substring(1, password.length() - 1);
      String firstChar = password.substring(0,1);
      String lastChar = password.substring(length - 1);



      password =  lastChar +  password_changed + firstChar;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, password);
     }
    }
```

You make an extra string (in this example password_changed) in wich you delete the first and last letter of the password variable. And you can use that new variable to change the password variable at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c[] = password.toCharArray();
char temp = c[0]
c[0] = c[password.length-1];
c[password.length-1] = temp;
```

There you go, swapping those two letters.
The `c[0]` will be your first letter, you store it in a `temp` variable, then modify the value of `c[0]` ( your first letter ) with the one in `c[password.length-1]` ( your last letter ) and then modify this value with the one store in the temp variable

Comment: I edited your answer because declaring a char array like that is discouraged

Comment: @Idos:  I rolled back your edit because it ultimately matters little in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Makoto what does matter ultimately in the grand scheme of things ?

Comment: The edit to the answer changed the array declaration.  Yes, it is better to declare your array as `char[] c`, but the way it is now doesn't make it any less accessible or any less difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The way you were getting the first character was correct, but not the middle or last.  Here's a solution showing all three cases:

```
  String password = "123456789";
  int length = password.length();

  String firstChar = password.substring(0, 1);
  String middle = password.substring(1, length - 1);
  String lastChar = password.substring(length - 1, length);

  password = lastChar + " " + middle + " " + firstChar;
  System.out.println(password);
```

This will print:

```
9 2345678 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much different than the other answers, but another way:

```
password = password.charAt(password.length() - 1)
           + password.substring(1, password.length() - 1)
           + password.charAt(0);
```